# Passing json "data" array in Retrofit 2

Tags: gson, retrofit2

I'm trying retrofit 2 for the first time and I have no idea how to tell it to get "Category" objects from an jsonarray named "data".

**Method 1**

If I do it like this it fails:

```
@GET("category")
Call<List<Category>> listCategories();
```

**Method 2**

But when I make a new model, called "Categories", which holds a List and is annotated with @SerializedName("data"), it works flawlessly.

```
@GET("category")
Call<Categories> listCategories();
```

**My Question**

Should I annotate something in the interface, like this

```
@GET("category")
@Annotation to look inside "data"
Call<List<Category>> listCategories();
```

Or should I annotate my "Category" model to tell Retrofit (or GSON) 
that it lives inside the json array "data"?

**JSON**

```
{"data":[{"id":1,"name":"Fist Name","parent":0},{"id":2,"name":"Second Name","parent":1}]}
```

Comment: post your request response data (json)

Comment: Question updated, thanks!

Comment: not worth it, but you can 1) implement custom gson deserializer for `List<Category>` 2) use OkHttp Interceptors something like https://github.com/square/okhttp/wiki/Interceptors Here is more info: https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/261 and https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/197

Answer (score 1):

**Method 2** Is correct and we use it when we dont want to use/define the json response object/arrays key names(field names). instead provide our own. **Eg.** In below code `List` object name is `items` but while Serialization and Deserialization it uses, what you have defined in [@SerializedName](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/index.html?com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html) annotation that is `data`.

```
public class Categories {

    //solution 1
    List<Category> data;//object name must match with the json response

    //solution 2
    @SerializedName("data")
    List<Category> items;
}
```

> Should I annotate something in the interface

No. There is no such annotation available and everything you can do is only in Response type class.